# Powershell Command to store Azure credentials in Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have a graph application and I am trying to install azure active directory for that and I am entering connecting commands every time is there any option where I can store commands so that I can use it in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any option where I can store commands so that I can use it in future.

*Yes there is a command where you can store the credentials and use the credentials to connect to the services.*

```
$AzureAdCred = Get-Credential
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $AzureAdCred
```

- *The first command will store the credentials in `$azureadcred`*
- *The next command will be connecting to the services in advance.*

[image]

*You can go through this Microsoft [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0#connect-to-azure-ad) if you want further clarification.*